# React+webpack+react-hot-loader dynamically json loading in table in production

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Good day, everyone.

I've got simple app with React+Webpack2+react-hot-loader that showing data-table from Json file.

```
import Data from '../../src/data/last.json';
```

And when I start "webpack-dev-server" all info showing by table dynamically changes without full page refresh, when "last.json" overwrites with another app.

I'm using examples from [GitHub react-hot-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/tree/next) and already read [WebPack off doc about HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/), which says that:

> The Hot Module Replacement functionality is not intended for use in production. You should only use it in your development configuration/environment.

Question: Can I ever achieve this behavior on production with hot-loader or only by ajax?

Or I need start using Redux with "*changing store on the fly*" on back-end?
Now i'm using php back-end with API's to front on React and I thought it'll be enough for my tasks. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot reloading is actual in development process where modifications is frequently occurred. Single page application in production is loaded once and worked on client side all time. When you release new version of application to production you need to push somehow signal to client side application to reload. The client side application performs reloading whenever it is suitable to application logic.

Your json file is hot-reloaded to client application after each modification because it is working process of webpack build and hot reloading. Usually, the data does not fall into the application via a file from the disk but as server program reply. And hot loading does not have such possibility to serve application data transfer. Your json file falls into application as a modified source file. Hot reloading is considering your json as source file and hot reloading it into application after changes.

Hot reloading is development building process. It is not application working process.

Comment: So, the only choice to achieve dynamically components reloading without full page refresh on production - is using Flux/Redux with the storages, right?

Comment: You have asked about json with data. If json have static data - you integrate it into the bundle with json loader (as in your string code sample). If json content is dinamic data - your aplication must perform request to server for that data. Now you asks about code component - it is genrally static and loaded as the bundle. When you release new version app, the server may be incompatible with previous client app only after all client apps fully reloaded to be compatible with new server code.

Comment: The flux/redux is application state manament approaches. What to use is your choise. Application state items may or may not be associated with server state. Your components designed to reflect application state.